# using security to importing CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED secutity codesigning

Tags: macos, code-signing, xcodebuild

Does anybody know why when I use 'security' on os x to import a valid identity that it seems to think it has expired:

There are 2 machines, my development machine and a jenkins slave.

I am using the xcodebuild to create an archive and then use:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath myApp.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -exportPath . PROVISIONING_PROFILE=fdd0caeb-58fb-41df-a5e8-e5e9bd1f95c9 "OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS=--keychain /Users/me/Library/Keychains/Buildsystem"
```

to build an ipa for the store. This works on my development machine using the same archive and the same exportOptions.plist but not on the jenkins slave. I get this error:

> 016-10-06 23:29:23.438 xcodebuild[87720:8494157] [MT] IDEDistribution:
>   -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path
>   '/var/folders/yd/l_8k4cn91kjc9r853crzz98m0000gn/T/MyApp_2016-10-06_23-29-23.437.xcdistributionlogs'.
>
> 2016-10-06 23:29:23.888 xcodebuild[87720:8494157] [MT]
>   IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error
>   1.)"
>
> error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)
>
> Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)"
>
> ** EXPORT FAILED **

I suspect it is because it thinks the code signing identity is bad. When I imported the identity as:

```
security import AP_Store.p12 -k /Users/me/Library/Keychains/Buildsystem -P *******  -T /usr/bin/codesign
```

then run:

```
security  find-identity
```

I get:

> 1) 71497439A2987BC6830DF2E4879DBD3A5F1B2857 "iPhone Distribution:
>   xxxxx  (xxxxxxxxx)" (CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED)

If I import the same identity on my development machine it says it is OK.

Does anybody know why the same identity would be OK on one machine but not another?

Comment: check your other machines system clock? Is it synced?

Comment: The date and time look good. It is running on a virtual machine if that makes any difference.

Comment: I found my problem, the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" had expired on the Jenkins slave machine. After replacing it everything started working.

[Check out MaintainingCertificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Comment: I was just about to comment to check the same.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by an expired intermediate certificate.

> Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority

had expired.

After replacing it everything worked.

A good reference is: [MaintainingCertificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.htmlhttp://)

Another thing that can lead to errors such as:

> 2016-10-11 11:41:11.780 xcodebuild[87463:15799133] [MT]
>   IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1
>   "(null)"
>
> error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)

is if you have an incorrect team ID in your exportOptions.plist file.